# how to execute RewriteRule same page with defferent query string?

Tags: .htaccess, content-management-system

I have this code  in a `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)$ index.php?menu=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)$ index.php?sub=$1 [NC]
```

The first `RewriteRule` has execute
but the second  `RewriteRule` does not execute.

How to execute `RewriteRule` same page with different query string as like above example?

Comment: I'm confused. What should the rewrite rule do? Currently they are both rewriting on the same trigger (^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)$) so it's first come first serve hence why only the first one is working. What is the desired effect of both rules?

Comment: You can't call twice only `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)$ index.php?menu=$1&sub=$1 [L]`